# Enum 2-ways binding with a Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to do a simple 2-ways binding with an enum to a Combobox but haven't found anything that works with my code so far.

**My enum (C#):**

```
public enum CurrenciesEnum { USD, JPY, HKD, EUR, AUD, NZD };
```

**The property the Enum should set / is bound to:**

```
    private string _ccy;
    public string Ccy
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ccy;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._ccy)
            {
                this._ccy= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Ccy");
            }
        }
    }
```

**The Xaml code that doesn't work:**

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Currencies" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type TypeName="ConfigManager:CurrenciesEnum" />
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Currencies}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Ccy, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: what's wrong? You get an error? No items in combobox? Combobox not displaying correct item? Bound item not changed when selected item in combobox changes?

Comment: The combobox itself is populated.
However when I select another value, the property doesn't seem to be updated - the object that contains that property is actually part of a lost that is displayed in a grid and changing line selection doesn't keep the ccy.

Comment: Sorry, actually the property is correctly set with the new value.
The issue seems to be binding back that newly set value to the ComboBox. Should I use a converter or something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is you are binding a `Enum` to a `string`, this will only work one way due to the default `ToString` operation in the binding engine.

If you are only using the `string` value change your `ObjectDataProvider` method name to `GetNames` this will return the string values for your `Enum` and will bind both ways, the other option is to not bind to a string but the `Enum` type.

```
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Currencies" MethodName="GetNames" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="ConfigManager:CurrenciesEnum" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

Comment: Thank you.
I've tried both ways you've suggested but it still doesn't work. Using Snoop, I see that the Ccy property correctly set when changingit in the ComboBoox. However, looking at the ComboBox, I see that... 1) I select EUR: [SelectedItem > EUR {Path=Ccy}, SelectedValue > EUR]. 2) I change focus and come back (my ComboBox should still show EUR, but it default back to USD): [SelectedItem > UAD {Path=Ccy}, SelectedValue > USD]

Comment: Looks that the reson is that the ComboBox when loaded for the first time is not using the value of the Ccy porperty but instead defaulting to the enum first value. Do I miss something in the mapping? Should it be OneWay instead? Or how could I stop the ComboBox to default?

Answer (score 0):

I load the enum into a Dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<T, string> EnumToDictionary<T>()
        where T : struct
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);

    // Can't use generic type constraints on value types,
    // so have to do check like this
    if (enumType.BaseType != typeof(Enum))
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be of type System.Enum");

    Dictionary<T, string> enumDL = new Dictionary<T, string>();
    //foreach (byte i in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
    //{
    //    enumDL.Add((T)Enum.ToObject(enumType, i), Enum.GetName(enumType, i));
    //}
    foreach (T val in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
    {
        enumDL.Add(val, val.ToString());
    }
    return enumDL;
}
```